# Update XML in Oracle using UPDATEXML

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, sql-update

I have an XML document like this one and I have to update value of `The time of begin` by new text. How to do this with UPDATEXML function, i.e. what is the XPath expression?

```
<dok>
    <dataSet>
        <foo>bla bla</foo>
        <field>START_DATE</field>
        <label>The time of begin</label>
    </dataSet>
    <dataSet>
        <bar>bla bla</bar>
        <label>The time of end</label>
        <field>END_DATE</field>
    </dataSet>
</dok>
```

My first idea was like this one:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET 
XML_COLUMN = UPDATEXML(XML_COLUMN, '/dok/dataSet/field/text()="START_DATE"/../label/text()', 'The date of start');
```

I don't like to use axis like `following-sibling`, because inside `dataSet` you may have various other elements in unknown order.

The rule shall be like: `Update "label" at "dataSet" where "field" = 'START_DATE'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To qualify elements like `field` (for example, only selecting one with a certain text content) use angle brackets. Also, it seems to me that the function is called UPDATEXML, not XMLUPDATE (see [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm)).

Try the following:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET XML_COLUMN =
   UPDATEXML(XML_COLUMN,
   '/dok/dataSet[field = "START_DATE"]/label/text()','The date of start');
```

Note: I'm familiar with XPath, not with SQL. But as far as I can see there might still be a missing WHERE clause in the above.

Comment: You are right, it was a typo. I correct my question for consistency. Yes, WHERE clause is missing but this was not the issue here.